# Property of 'nested' object only 'found' after the second call

Tags: python

I have the strange problem that the property of the nested/inner object, here foo, is only 'found' when called twice. What is the reason for that?

```js
class OuterClass():
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self.foo_instance = foo_instance


class Foo():
    def getdata(self):
        return 42 
    @property
    def outputs(self):
        self.outputs = self.getdata()


# Main
foo_instance = Foo()
outerbar = OuterClass(foo_instance)
print outerbar.foo_instance.outputs
# wrong output: None
print outerbar.foo_instance.outputs
# correct output: 5
```

**DISCLAIMER**

Not sure if I use the right terms, so please feel free to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you use properties.

What you are doing is replacing the property of the object with the actual value that should be returned by the property, that means the first time `outputs` is called that `outputs` is replaced by the value of `getdata` and the function itself returns `None`. The second time `outputs` is no longer a property, it is the return value of `getdata`.

The correct way of using properties is simply returning the value.

```
class Foo():
    def getdata(self):
        return 42

    @property
    def outputs(self):
        return self.getdata()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first access reaches the end of the function and hence returns `None`. As a side effect, it shadows the class attribute with an instance attribute. The second access returns the shadowing value.

```
  @property
  def outputs(self):
      return self.getdata()
```